# how to query multiple arrays in Mongod DB

Tags: mongodb

Here are some records in my collection:

```
{ id: 1, arrayA: [1, 2, 3], arrayB: [4, 5, 6]},
{ id: 2, arrayA: [2, 4], arrayB: [1, 5]},
{ id: 3, arrayA: [1, 6], arrayB: [2, 3, 4]},
{ id: 4, arrayA: [2, 6], arrayB: [1, 3, 4]},
{ id: 5, arrayA: [1, 4, 5], arrayB: [2, 3, 6]},
{ id: 6, arrayA: [2, 4, 5], arrayB: [2, 3]}
....
```

How do I construct a query that takes an array of numbers (call it inputArray) and would fetch records that contain in either arrayA or arrayB all the numbers specified by inputArray.

If inputArray is [2, 6], then the query would be: find all records that have 2 and 6 in either arrayA or arrayB.

This should return:

id 1: because 2 is in arrayA and 6 is in arrayB

id 3: because 2 is in arrayB and 6 is in arrayA

id 4: because 2 is in arrayA and 6 is in arrayA

id 5: because 2 is in arrayB and 6 is in arrayB

This is the best I could come up with:

```
db.collection.find({$or: [    
  {arrayA: {$all: [2, 6]}},
  {arrayB: {$all: [2, 6]}},
  {$and: [
    {arrayA: {$in: [2, 6]}},
    {arrayB: {$in: [2, 6]}}    
  ]}
]})
```

I am just surprised that there isn't any better way!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's another version (don't ask me about the efficiency of this :) )

```
db.ma.find({$or: [{arrayA: 2, arrayB: 6}, 
                  {arrayA: 6, arrayB: 2}, 
                  {arrayA: {$all: [2,6]}}, 
                  {arrayB: {$all: [2, 6]}}]})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your query doesn't work with record id 4. if 2 and 6 are in arrayA and neither in arrayB then your query fails. "...records that have 2 and 6 in **either arrayA or arrayB**"

Comment: This should work better: 

`db.collection.find({$or: [

  {arrayA: {$all: [2, 6]}}, 

  {arrayB: {$all: [2, 6]}}, 

  {$and: [

    {arrayA: {$in: [2, 6]}}, 

    {arrayB: {$in: [2, 6]}}

  ]}

]})`  I am just surprised that there isn't any better way.

Comment: Did you test it? It doesn't find anything on my machine.